# ember-cli server with http-mocks with no path returns JSON when page refreshed

Tags: node.js, ember.js, express, ember-cli

I have ember-cli set up with http-mocks. In the generated server files, the endpoints all begin with '/api'. In my app, the actual server is returning the API data on the root domain (i.e. http://myclient.com fetches data from http://myapi.com), so I removed that path.

When I load the app from the root in development, everything works fine. However, when I load the app from a path (i.e. http://localhost:4200/books vs http://localhost:4200), I get the JSON from the server mock. This means I can't refresh the app if I'm not on the root.

Is there a way to make sure that the ember-cli server only returns the mock JSON if it's got a JSON accept header, or something similar?

Comment: Is question about how to use `namespace: 'api'` in development and no namespace in production?

Comment: That would be one possible solution, sure